# Apollo graphql's documentation state that "client" is a properties of result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo

Apol[image]

In the code below the I do not see client returned from result

```
    <Mutation
                mutation={LOGIN}
                variables={{
                ...this.state
            }}>
                {(login,result) => {
                    console.log(result);
                    return (
                        <Form
                            onSubmit={(e) => {
                            e.preventDefault()
                            return login()>
                              //Some Form Details 
                        </Form>
                    )
                }
      }

            </Mutation>
```

Rather I see the following.These object does not contain the client property that the documentation states. What is the issue? Is it deprecated, a bug or something I am not doing correctly in the setup?

[image]

Comment: See that you have passed it in ApolloProvider. 
One more thing try to pass it in Mutation props then try to access it in render prop.

Comment: New react hooks are also available for use.